# vue not running variable saved in instance

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to Vue js, working with examples in docs on Codesandbox. This code showing me error

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "todos" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I couldn't detect where is the problem exactly.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ol>
      <li v-bind:key="todo.text" v-for="todo in todos">{{ todo.text }}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
      { text: "Learn Vue" },
      { text: "Build something awesome" }
    ]
  }
});
</script>

<style>
style here
</style>
```

Here is a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x77r1lwrlz) of the code and the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code.
The todos variable you declared was not in the instance of vue.

You should declare your data property as below.

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <ol>
      <li v-bind:key="todo.text" v-for="todo in todos">{{ todo.text }}</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [
        { text: "Learn JavaScript" },
        { text: "Learn Vue" },
        { text: "Build something awesome" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/9o2036km1r

Comment: Thank you for correcting. But now I feel confused as the examples provided in official docs not working.

Comment: Which example? I think this link can help understanding the data function with components.https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function